# How to bet on Japanese government bonds interest rate going up in the coming years?

Tags: interest-rate, government-bonds, speculation, japan

Is there a way for a private individual investor to bet on Japanese Government bonds interest rate going up in the coming years?

Comment: Do you mean like [Intrade](http://www.intrade.com) style?

Answer (score 2):

When the **interest rate of a bond goes up**, the **price of the bond goes down**

So, to bet that the interest rate going up, you just have to **short the bond** itself.

For that, you have to **find a broker** that allows you to trade Japanese government bonds.

I don't want to advertise any broker in particular, but I know that AvaFx allows you to trade Japanese governement bonds.

Answer (score 1):

Found something here:
http://www.moneyweek.com/investments/bonds/japanese-government-bonds-the-best-trade-ever-52926

I do not have time (yet) to read, understand and summarize the strategy, nor do I endorse it. The title is indeed hyped. I just posted the link for those who are interested in the subject. Feel free to update my post with a summary, or propose a better answer.

Comment: I think the drive-by downvote was because you just posted a short answer with a link.  Better to quote some (but not all) of the relevant text from the article, so the answer can stand somewhat alone, plus give people a clue what they're going to find at the link.

Comment: sorry, that was me, and I got myself pulled away before I commented. the reasons Chris said are accurate, plus the fact that it's labeled "The best trade ever" is just icing. ick / hype.

Comment: @fennec Agreed. I read the article (hyped title), posted March 2011. It was a strategy based on JGB (Japanese government bonds) futures, with the assumption that rates wouldn't fall much more, since they were only 1.5% then. Bad move. Read comments by folks who were underwater in the trade in following months. Does it make sense now though? Maybe, but I want to see an explanation why, not just a URL. But one down vote was enough, so I'm just leaving this overly long comment ;o)

Comment: I understand downvotes when there are better answers, but in the absence of any input mine is (IMHO) a tiny step in understanding.

Comment: The premise of the article is plausible, but the credibility of the author was undermined for me by this: "The yield on the ten-year JGB fell from 6.75% in November 1989 to below 1% in 2010. That's a capital gain of 53% on top of 20 years of interest income of 6.75%." If it's a ten-year bond, how do you get 20 years of interest from it?